# Light waves falling into a black hole

Tags: black-holes, astrophysics, tidal-effect

We know that as light falls into a black hole it is stretched due to unequal tidal forces acting on it and hence it looses energy . Then is it possible that as the light gets stretched each succeeding term of wavelength forms a progression? Like an A.P , G.P or H.P?

Comment: You need to take into account where the light falling in is observed from, near the photon or far away from the black hole. Related to; http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/107945/light-entering-a-black-holes-singularity

Comment: From both the reference frames . 1st from the frame of an outside observer and then from the reference frame of the photon .

Comment: What are AP, GP and HP?

Comment: I don't think that light would be stretched, more exactly there is currently no theory what could describe quantummechanical phenomena in strongly curved spacetime.

Comment: A.P - Arithmetic progression , G.P - Geometric Progression and H.P - Harmonic Progression .

Comment: Am I misunderstanding something ?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that light would be stretched, more exactly there is currently no theory what could describe quantummechanical phenomena in strongly curved spacetime. But a lot of people are working hardly on that.

Even if there would be such a theory, this "tidal stretch of the photons" wouldn't happen around the event horizon, but nearing the singularity inside it. On the EH, the curvetime of the spacetime ($\approx$ tidal stretch) is not unavoidably high, and it shrinks with the mass of the BH. The high curvature is around the singularity.

The cause of the wavelength growth nearing the event horizon is not some "tidal force", but the gravitational time dilation.

Answer (score 2):

We know that as light falls into a black hole it is "compressed" due to unequal coordinate velocities of its different parts.

As light falls, its coordinate velocity decreases. The upper end of a light pulse is closing on the lower end of the light pulse, because the lower end has fallen more and has lower coordinate velocity.